# Bootstrap navbar-collapsed not keeping background after shrinking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: before shrinking]

[image: after shrinking]

```css
.normal {
height: 75px;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.normal .navbar-right {
padding-top: 12px;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;
}




@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar{height: auto;}
    .navbar-brand{
    height: auto;}
    
}
.navbar-collapse{
border: 0px;

}
.navbar-brand {
padding: 0px !important;
}
.navbar-brand img {
max-height: 75px;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.shrink {
height: 50px;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.shrink .navbar-right {
padding-top: 0px;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.shrink .navbar-brand img {
max-height: 50px;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-ms-transition: 0.5s;
transition: 0.5s;
}
body {
min-height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top normal" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed button-middle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x70" /></a>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     </ul>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
    <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
    <li><a href="./">Fixed top</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

With the `.navbar{height: auto;}` I fixed the background issue of losing background of navbar-collapsed before scrolling.
The problem is fixing the navbar-collapsed background issue after scrolling when the navbar is shrinked because is interfering with the content after the navbar...

Comment: Other than your HTML having an extra `</ul>` that shouldn't be there, there is nothing wrong with it. Here it is: http://www.bootply.com/render/TLiPJCFBER

Comment: The thing is, after scrolling down, navbar-fixed-top gets shrinked and the navbar-collapsed gets disconnected like in picture 2. It affects the next content on the body as the collapsed bar gets transparent

<script>
   $(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(document).scrollTop() > 150) {
   $('.navbar').addClass('shrink');
   }
   else {
   $('.navbar').removeClass('shrink'); }
   });
  </script>

Comment: That's not happening for me.

Comment: apparently fixed height for .shrink was a mistake, and apparently my question too... thanks anyway for taking a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed    `height: 50px;` needs to be deleted from the css .shrink class

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: That was a complete answer. Actually this is the only answer I needed.